# How to solve TypeScript `possibly null` error within ternary?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to add a ternary operator to add a class:

```
className={clsx(classes.text, {
   classes.textSmall]: children.length > 11,
})}
```

This works but I get a TypeScript error:

> Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.  TS2533

I'm not sure what can be improved here. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Which object is possibly `null` or `undefined`? Is it `classes` or `children`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Typescript version 3.7 you can use nullish coalescing and optional property access to deal with possibly null values within a ternary:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining

I'm assuming here that children is the possibly null value, here are some examples:

```
// Optional property access, double bang operator because it will resolve to undefined if the property is undefined
foo: !!(children?.length > 11);

// With nullish coalescing
bar: children?.length ?? 0 > 11;

// Without either
baz: children && children.length > 11;
```